VS code is not able to activate the conda environment automatically all of a sudden. How to resolve this issue?
Do I need to enter anything in workspace settings (JSON)?
Usually, it automatically activates the environment once you open the integrated terminal of VS Code.
I tried deleting and generating the virtual environment to see if it worked, but it still does not automatically activate the environment. Also, I tried restarting the Laptop, but that too did not help.
Also, I have following condition already marked as True in the Settings.
"python.terminal.activateEnvironment": true
